# How to get a taxonomy by a term slug?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

For example, if I have a custom taxonomy called "custom-category" and the term "WordPress", is there any way to get the taxonomy "custom-category" by term slug "wordpress".

This cant be used: `get_term_by('slug', 'wordpress')` since I have slug not term id.

USE CASE:

```
$tag = get_term_by('slug', 'wordpress');


$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'custom-post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => $tag->taxonomy,
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'wordpress' )
        )
    ),
) );
```

Comment: Have you tried your example? `get_term_by('slug', 'wordpress');` doesn't require the term ID. Though you may need the taxonomy: `get_term_by('slug', 'wordpress', 'custom-category');`

Comment: I already tried `get_term_by('slug', 'wordpress')`. Since I have term_slug, the taxonomy name is required but this is what I need to get.

Comment: A slug could be in multiple taxonomies. But I'm having trouble imagining a situation where you wouldn't know the taxonomy. That suggests a bigger problem. Why do you need to get the taxonomy from a slug?

Comment: I am writing a shortcode to get custom posts. I have the post type and term slug to get posts. There are many custom taxonomies and post types. I have added the use case in the question.

Comment: No, you can't, unless you're certain that your terms will never share the same slug - terms in different taxonomy can have the same slug. And even if you're certain, you'd need to write custom SQL to get the taxonomy (slug) of the specific term. So why bother, your shortcode could just implement a parameter for the taxonomy, e.g. `[my-shortcode term="slug-here" tax="taxonomy"]`.

Comment: Or a separate argument for each taxonomy: `[my-shortcode taxonomy="slug-here" taxonomy-two="slug-here"]`